# VBScript debugger implementation - IActiveScriptDebug "Catastrophic failure" on 64-bit Windows

Tags: delphi, debugging, vbscript

Following on from my last question on implementing the Microsoft Active Script debugger interfaces on 64 bit windows. I have come across another intractable problem.

This time it's with IActiveScriptDebug which doesn't seem to work in its 64 bit incarnation.

The code in question is when attempting to set breakpoints using the code from MS example debugger code (converted to Delphi).

```
  Href:=FEngine.QueryInterface(IID_IActiveScriptDebug,FdebugEngine);
  Href:=FdebugEngine.EnumCodeContextsOfPosition(0,Line,LineLen,edcc);
  if IEnumDebugCodeContexts(edcc).Next(1,dcc,numFetched) = S_OK then
    Href:=dcc.SetBreakPoint(BREAKPOINT_ENABLED);
```

Where Fengine is the IactiveScript Language engine and FdebugEngine is the returned IActiveScriptDebug object and edcc is a IEnumDebugCodeContexts;

IID_IActiveScriptDebug is set to the IID_IActiveScriptDebug64 GUID for 64bit windows and IID_IActiveScriptDebug32 for 32 bit windows. In both cases a valid debug engine is returned.

Compiled for 32 windows, this code works fine. I can set breakpoints and the get the callbacks on breaks.

Compiled for 64 bit, FdebugEngine.EnumCodeContextsOfPosition returns a "Catastrophic failure" Hresult.

Any ideas why the 64 bit code produces this error ?

Comment: Have you obtained and passed the cookie value mentioned in the 3rd occurence of EnumCodeContextsOfPosition in this (rather antique) article http://e.craft.free.fr/ActiveScriptingLostFAQ/hostdebug.htm#HD24?

Comment: @MartynA According the official MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/winscript/reference/iactivescriptdebug-enumcodecontextsofposition .The cookie value passed is 0, so that is correct, that is what is set in IActiveScriptParse::ParseScriptText. This works in 32 bit mode.

Comment: @MartynA I tried creating a IDebugDocumentHelper object and following the recommended code through on that site you linked to to get a cookie value and passed that on to the EnumCodeContextsOfPosition function. Same result "Catastrophic failure". I'm a bit stumped now,

Comment: Well, as I imagine you've guessed, I'm no expert at this, so the best I can suggest is that you expand your q into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and hope that t catches the attention of someone who is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much chasing my tail and the lack of responses from this forum, I have come to the conclusion that the 64 bit version of the Active script debugger is broken and there is no prospect of it getting fixed as it seems to be deprecated.

So I leave this here as a warning to anybody wanting to implement this feature and let them know not to waste their time.